# Barb adapter with EVA Barrier Hose

Tags: beer, fermenter, berliner-weisse, closed-transfer

I recently purchased EVA Barrier Beer Line and DuoTight disconnects.

But the problem arises when I am trying to do the closed transfer from my fermenter as it's tap is not compatible with the EVA Barrier.

Fermenter Tap is a barb type hence not sure how to connect with hose.

Please see the pictures[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the barb with something more suitable.  One possibility: [this](https://www.brewhardware.com/product_p/flarem14xmnpt12.htm) 1/2" NPT to 1/4" flare adaptor, plus a swivel flare fitting such as [this](https://www.brewhardware.com/product_p/fflbarb14.htm) (EVAbarrier can be softened in hot water and pre-expanded with an awl, pliers, a pen cap to then fit over the swivel).